# How to calculate percentage difference - mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am working with a real-estate database with 2 Tables: Sales (Mutation) and House (bien).
The Sales Table has amount (ValeurFonciere) attribute, and House Table has Type of Real Estate (TypeLoc; i.e. apartment or house), Number of Rooms (NoPP), and square meters (SurCar1) attributes.

I now need to find the percentage difference of the Price/m² between 2 room and 3 room apartments.

I know how to get the average price/m² for either type of appartment;

```
select NoPP, avg(ValeurFonciere/SurCar1)
FROM mutation, bien
where mutation.Bien_ID = bien.Bien_ID
and NoPP = 2
and TypeLoc = "Appartement";
```

but I have no idea how to combine the 2 using the percentage difference formula
((A-B)/((A+B)/2))*100: with A being NoPP=2 and B being NoPP=3.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

You can create derived tables using subqueries for each condition

```
SELECT ((A-B)/((A+B)/2))*100
FROM
(
    select avg(ValeurFonciere/SurCar1) as A, 1 as key
    FROM mutation, bien
    where mutation.Bien_ID = bien.Bien_ID
    and NoPP = 2
    and TypeLoc = "Appartement"
) two
JOIN
(
    select avg(ValeurFonciere/SurCar1) as B, 1 as key
    FROM mutation, bien
    where mutation.Bien_ID = bien.Bien_ID
    and NoPP = 3
    and TypeLoc = "Appartement"
) three
ON two.key = three.key
```

Answer (score 0):

select (100/(ValeurFonciere/SurCar1)   - (select 100/(ValeurFonciere/SurCar1)

FROM mutation, bien

where mutation.Bien_ID = bien.Bien_ID

and NoPP = 2

and TypeLoc = "Appartement" ) ) as 'price'

FROM mutation, bien

where mutation.Bien_ID = bien.Bien_ID

and NoPP = 3

and TypeLoc = "Appartement"